# Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-hooks

I have gone through other similar questions and tried to implement the solutions there. But I guess I just need to understand why this isn't working for my case.
I am trying to DRY my code by calling headers from a utils file and then using it on different apis.
I would like some guidance on why this isnt working.

**headers.tsx**

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

const useHeaders = () => {
    const { data: Session } = useSession();
  
    let token = ""
    if (Session){
        // @ts-ignore
        token = Session.accessToken
    }

    const authToken = `Bearer ${token}`;

    return {
      headers: {
        Authorization: authToken,
      },
    };
  };

  export default useHeaders
```

**users.tsx**

```
import axios from "axios";
import useHeaders from "../../utils/headers"

export function fetchUsers() {
  const headers = useHeaders();
  const url =  `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VEXO_URL}/v1/ke/user/list`
    
    return axios
      .get(url, headers)
      .then((res) => res)
      .catch((err) => err);
  }
```

Comment: This might help: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html.

Answer (score 0):

This a common reactJs error where react prevent the using of hooks outside react component you should convert `fetchUsers` function to a hook

also Only use hooks in components and custom hooks